# UI Frozen on Honeycomb

Tags: android

I'm testing an app on multiple devices that uses [Chris Banes' Pull to Refresh library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshListView.java) - it works fine on other devices, but has an odd quirk on the HTC Flyer (Honeycomb), Motorola Xoom Family Edition (Honeycomb) and the Honeycomb emulator.

I have the PullToRefreshListView packed with ImageViews and as I scroll up and down, testing the pull to refresh functionality, sometimes the screen freezes (on the Flyer, it's extremely reliable--pull to refresh once and it freezes).

The UI is no longer updated on this Activity. It still registers touch events; I can tap buttons that go to other Activities and they will load and work properly, but when I return to the frozen Activity the UI is still frozen. I can also scroll the ListView and see log statements indicating rows are scrolling, but nothing changes on the screen. I even set a Thread to update elements on the screen every second, but when it freezes I do not see those changes.

Letting it sit for a few minutes does nothing. I don't get an Application Not Responding error. What could cause the UI to not refresh, without actually blocking the UI thread?

Comment: Updated: the issue appears to occur on all Honeycomb devices, not just the HTC Flyer, and experimentation suggests the issue is only with Pull to Refresh--the Ignition library RemoteImageView is not relevant.

Comment: It was a while back, but I think this may have done the trick: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/commit/420b36aa1fb78946baea9e5d9183489486c11e61 but yes, it was a Pull to Refresh library issue for me, and only a Honeycomb problem.